# how can I get the last 5 items (from 15) of a bar plot in palantir foundry workshop?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

Lets say I have 15 items in my bar plot. If I sort it, and I want the last 5 items, how can I do this? (so instead the first 5, the last 5)

Answer (score 0):

To limit the display to just 5 items, you can set that in the config panel for the relevant plot layer.
[plot layer config panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHzAG.png)

Then, to display the first 5 or last 5 items, change the sort order in the config panel for the chart widget -- pick either Value Ascending or Value Descending depending on which gives you the result you're after.
[chart widget config panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isf4Y.png)